# A 'list' object is not callable on Decimal list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, fatal-error

I get `'list' object is not callable` when I call `sum` against an `Decimal` list. See the command line session bellow.

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> d = map(Decimal, u'0.97 + .03'.split('+'))
>>> d
[Decimal('0.97'), Decimal('0.03')]
>>> sum(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I am using python `2.7.3`. The expected output of `sum(d)` here is `1.00`

I see its working as stated in Python website. http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial

Comment: What does type(sum) evaluate to?

Comment: `>>> type(sum) <type 'list'>`

Comment: @Muquaddim -- there's your problem.  You've shadowed the builtin `sum` function by creating a list with the same name somewhere ...

Comment: looks like you defined a variable name `sum` in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you have a local variable called `sum` earlier in your code of type list and that is why you get this error. In python, you can rebind any builtin function. You can still invoke the builtin function `sum` by by using the `__builtin__` module.

```
>>> sum = [] # override builtin sum function
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = map(Decimal, ['0.97', '0.03'])
>>> sum(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>> __builtins__.sum(d)
Decimal('1.00')
```

I would however recommend not naming your local variables after builtin function or types. A good way to catch those errors is to run [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) Python static code checker on your code. Some editor or IDE allow easy integration with pylint.